# Getting 404 Not Found using angular-apollo graphql client

Tags: angular, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

So I'm integrating graphql into our new app. I instantiated the Apollo client with our graphql API endpoint, but I'm not able to make any query, in fact, I'm not even able to see any post(graphql) request going in through the network tab.

I get an options request resulting in 404 Not found.

The graphql endpoint works perfectly fine in tools looks for insomnia.

I googled about it and found out that it requires CORS to be added on the server. Even after doing that it's giving the same behavior

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it has anything to do with Apollo Angular or your JavaScript code. It stops on `OPTIONS` which probably means you have CORS configured incorrectly.

Comment: Yea, that was exactly the issue!